# Is there a custom firmware that will disable reset button/return to factory defaults for an Asus AC RT-56U?

Tags: openwrt, tomato

I've been searching for information on the individual sites (DD-WRT, Open Wrt, Tomato, etc.), and finding nothing. One forum (not in DD-WRT site) indicated that DD-WRT does have a switch in its GUI that allows one to turn off the router button, but I haven't been able to confirm whether the build for this modem includes this feature.

ASUS-Merlin does not support this.

I need this for the purpose of preventing a reboot and default to factory password to circumvent access controls. I've read a lot of "keep your kid away from it," "talk to your kid," etc. and so forth, but in this instance it is **me** that needs to be controlled--burgeoning internet addiction. "Get help" etc. isn't what I'm asking for either, in terms of a response. I'd really appreciate an answer on point, that isn't disparaging :). Just want to know if using a custom firmware is an option, and if so, what firmware might support it.

Oh: and some say to desolder or put some super glue in there, or disassemble the machine and take out the button. The latter I could probably do, but I'd **really** like to avoid modding the hardware.

Thanks much in advance. :)

Comment: So, if you brick the router, what is your plan?

Comment: Thanks for the nice, on-point response! Giving pw to buddy who is hanging on to it for me, and "if your router should brick on you to where you can't boot it up...then you MUST use JTAG to recover the router....the reset button will not work to clear out a bad parameter from nvram"

Answer (score 2):

DD-WRT does allow you to disable the reset button. I'm on version "DD-WRT v3.0-r35681 std (04/06/18)" and I am using a TP-Link Archer C7 Router. The setting is under: Administration Tab > Management Sub Tab > Reset Button Section. Then select "Disable".

I'd *assume* this setting is the same for all routers (like Asus), but can only confirm for my own setup.

Comment: It only disables it when the ROM is running, you can still access recovery mode and clear settings at start-up.

Comment: @acejavelin can you explain more ?

Comment: @minanageh I Guess I am not sure what you want me to explain... if you disable the reset button, it is disabled when the router is running, but there is no way to disable the 30-30-30 hard reset on a router, that is the method to reflash/restore it stock and is essentially a recovery mode, it can't be disabled. What more do you want me to explain? There is a link to the 30-30-30 method in the next answer that explains more, but it essentially is a small piece of code installed in write protected memory that you can't erase or modify and it's used to recovery a dead device.

Answer (score 1):

You have no choice here. There is no way to disable [30-30-30 hard resets](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30), and even if it exists it would be totally architecture/manufacturer dependend. This kind of code block ([CFE](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/bootloader/cfe) / preboot) is pretty much proprietary, and thats why custom roms can only change the behavior of your Router firmware after it booted.

If you have the balls to do it, the CFE code of [some legacy Asus Routers](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blob/master/release/src-rt-6.x/cfe/cfe/arch/common/board/bcm947xx/src/bcm947xx_devs.c#L116) is available online and you need to edit to disable this button. But by doing this you could even be sued by Broadcom since they are company that dont respect it's customers when it comes from their Wifi products (if you know what Broadcom does to allow distribution of it's modules by DD-WRT folks, or if you have ever used a broadcom wifi nic you know what i'm talking about...).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could open up the box and prevent physical Access to the button nu shimming it, or using a tamperseal.
Though 30-30-30 means HW access and that would be the issue you should be preventing ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172502)